# Solving for Congruence Class

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I’m trying to solve the following problem:

> Find all solutions to [11][x]^46 + [45][x]^11 = [4] in Z55 with 0 <= x < 55.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: What do you get when you take mod 11 and mod 5?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What do you get when you take mod 11 and mod 5?

> $x \equiv x^{11} \equiv 4 \pmod{11} $. This has solutions $ x \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$.
>  $x^2 \equiv  x^{46} \equiv 4 \pmod{5} $. This has solutions $ x \equiv 2, 3 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: There is an error somewhere (besides being very incomplete).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

If $11x^{46}+45x^{11}\equiv4\bmod55$, then $x^{46}\equiv4\bmod 5$ and $x^{11}\equiv4\bmod11$.

But from Fermat's little theorem, we know 
$x^{11}\equiv x\bmod 11.$

Also $x\not\equiv0\bmod 5,$ or else we'd have $x^{46}\equiv0\bmod5$,

so $x^4\equiv1\bmod5$, so $x^{46}\equiv x^2\bmod5$.

Since $x^{2}\equiv4\bmod5$, we have $x\equiv\pm2\bmod5$.

So $x\equiv4\bmod11$ and $x\equiv\pm2\bmod5$.  Do you know how to solve that mod $55$?

Comment: Not only can we solve it mod $55$ but we can *easily* solve it $\bmod p(2p+1)$ due to the special innate structure that enables such - see my answer which highlights that (designed) structure.

Comment: How can I solve x ≡ ± 2mod5 ?

Comment: $x\equiv2$ or $3\bmod5$

Comment: should I choose either x = 2 or 3 mod 5 and solve x with x=4 mod 11? Since the two equations contradict

Comment: yes, there is one solution $\pmod{55}$ for which $x\equiv2\pmod5$ and another for which $x\equiv3\pmod5$

Answer (score 0):

Put $\,p=5,\, a=2,\, T=46\,$ below, which highlights innate structure enabling the simple solution, i.e. by CRT it is equivalent to $\,x^2\equiv a^2\pmod{\!p},\ x\equiv a^2 \pmod{\!q}\,$ which is easily solvable as below.

**Theorem** $ $ If $\,p\,$ and  $\,q = 2p+1\,$ are primes and $\,\color{#c00}{T\equiv 2}\pmod{p\!-\!1}$

$\qquad\qquad\ \bmod pq\!:\,\ \ a^2 \equiv\, q\, x^{\color{#c00}T} - 2p\, x^{\large q} \iff x\equiv a^2\color{#0a0}{-(a^2\pm a)}q$

**Proof** $ $ Applying CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem and little Fermat we have

$\!\!\bmod q\!:\ {-2}p\equiv 1\,$ so $\ a^2 \equiv 0+1\cdot x^{\large q}\equiv\, x\iff x =\color{#90f}{ a^2\!+\!j\,q}\ $ for $\,j\in\Bbb Z$

$\!\!\bmod p\!:\ \ \ \ \ \  q\equiv 1\,$ so $\,a^{2}\equiv 1\cdot x^{\large\color{#c00}2}-0\!\!\iff\! \pm a\equiv x\equiv \color{#90f}{a^2\!+\! \color{#0a0}j\,q} \equiv a^2\!+\!j\!\iff\! \color{#0a0}{j\equiv \pm a -a^2}$

Comment: so the answer to OP's question is $x\equiv a^2+(\pm a -a^2)q\bmod pq$

Comment: @J.W.T Yes OP is special case $\,p=5,\ a=2\ $ as I said.